# Exclude certain product IDs from Firebase conversion tracking?

Tags: ios, firebase, in-app-purchase, firebase-analytics

Firebase by default is using purchases of my non-consumable IAP and my monthly subscription option both as `in_app_purchase` conversions on iOS. Is there a way I can have it only count the non-consumable purchases as a conversion so that I am able to target my Google Ads to users likely to purchase the non-consumable IAP and not either that or the subscription?

If not, is the best way to achieve this to just log a custom event and use that event for the in-app actions option on Google Ads?

```
Analytics.logEvent("one_time_purchase", parameters: [AnalyticsParameterPrice : self.purchasePrice])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to exclude certain product ID's upon further research. I solved this problem by logging a custom event only when that product ID was successfully purchased, and then tailored my Google Ads to that conversion event.